# System.console.readPassword() requires user to press enter Before reading Password

Tags: java, console

I have a problem while reading input through console class.

The readPassword() method does not start reading until a enter key is pressed in the console, and will keep displaying the characters in the console.

Post user inputs a enter key in console, the read password starts to read the characters from console.

I wonder if this has something to do with getting the lock in the console through the synchronized keyword in the ReadPassword() function.

code for ReadPassword function -

```
public char[] readPassword(String fmt, Object ... args) {
        char[] passwd = null;
        synchronized (writeLock) {
            synchronized(readLock) {
                try {
                    echoOff = echo(false);
                } catch (IOException x) {
                    throw new IOError(x);
                }
                IOError ioe = null;
                try {
                    if (fmt.length() != 0)
                        pw.format(fmt, args);
                    passwd = readline(true);
                } catch (IOException x) {
                    ioe = new IOError(x);
                } finally {
                    try {
                        echoOff = echo(true);
                    } catch (IOException x) {
                        if (ioe == null)
                            ioe = new IOError(x);
                        else
                            ioe.addSuppressed(x);
                    }
                    if (ioe != null)
                        throw ioe;
                }
                pw.println();
            }
        }
        return passwd;
    }
```